# can we bind 3 controls into a single control in android?

Tags: android

I have 2 textviews and one imageview and i want to bind them into a single control so that i can implement horizontalScrollView on them...

Is there a way to merge different controls so that we can use them???

Or is there a way to implement horizontalScrollView on multiple controls simulataneously??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can build an xml layout that you inflate into a GaleryView. Android allows you to build any mashup of controls into a layout and then use that layout for each row in a listview or each item in a sliding galery.

in a ListAdapter you can inflate the layout and set all of the properties.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = factory.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    TextView main = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.labelMain);
    TextView details = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.labelDetails);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon); 

    main.setText(_items.get(position).Title); 
    details.setText(_items.get(position).Description);
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin);

    return row;
}
```

Comment: i did something similar like that...anyways thanks alot for the reply!!